# What Suction Cups Were Used To Climb Trump Tower?

Tags: climbing

There is a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvwUip4d2no).

[image: Man climbing]

Basically I won't say I'm planning to do the same thing but would like to find out more behind how he did it.  Someone told me the suction cups were intended for construction and not climbing but I'm not really sure.

**[The following which looks similar requires an air compressor.](http://www.ggrglass.co.uk/suction-cups/nv11-fairs-air-powered-suction-cup/) If it requires a small air compressor how did Steve do it?**

Comment: Just in case you *are* planning a repeat, make sure to check out the current conditions on [mountainproject](https://www.mountainproject.com/v/suction-aid-route/112063080)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they were four  [NV11 Fairs Air Powered Suction Cups](http://www.ggrglass.co.uk/suction-cups/nv11-fairs-air-powered-suction-cup/) as pointed out by this [article](http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/10/politics/trump-tower-suction-cups/).

Comment: "Requires small air compressor (not sold by GGR Group)" how did he do it then?

Comment: @William I am guessing that he had a small air compressor and a battery in his backpack, but I doubt the NYPD will be providing much information as they probably want to avoid a repeat.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/LifeLine-AAA-300-Volt-Compressor/dp/B000SL4AA2/ref=sr_1_1?s=power-hand-tools&ie=UTF8&qid=1473297076&sr=1-1&keywords=mini+air+compressor like this

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be four of the [NV11 Fairs Air Powered Suction Cup](http://www.ggrglass.co.uk/suction-cups/nv11-fairs-air-powered-suction-cup/) as already stated by [Charlie Brumbaugh](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/8794/charlie-brumbaugh) in his [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/13805/8060).

There are a lot of sources which claim that they were the used equipment. However, there is no real statement from the climber/police (!):

> The man appeared to be relying on a series of NV11 Fairs Air Powered
>   Suction Cups, which retail at $280.22 each. The product is marketed as
>   able to lift up to 150 lbs, being ideally suited to picking up glass
>   or stone surfaces.

<sub>From [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/08/10/politics/trump-tower-suction-cups/)</sub>

### NV11 Fairs Air Powered Suction Cup

[image: NV11 Fairs Air Powered Suction Cup]

> Semi-porous loads can be handled safely with this innovative air
>   powered suction cup.
>
> Ideal for textured glass or slightly porous stone surfaces, this
>   unique Air Powered NV11 Fairs suction cup is designed for use with a
>   compressed air supply to ensure optimum safety and provide peace of
>   mind during lifting. The high-flow pad attaches quickly during
>   operation without the need for pumping and has an extra tough
>   all-metal handle. This specialist heavy duty suction cup is highly
>   suited to lifted and setting of semi-porous paving and stone flooring
>   tiles.
>
> Key features:
>
> - Lifts 68kg
> - 250mm (10 inches) diameter lipped pad with closed cell foam
>     ring
> - Supplied with protective carrying case
> - Vacuum is applied and released with quick action pump handle
> - Red line indicator warns of any vacuum loss
> - Supplied with 12 month warranty
> - Packaging Dimensions & Weight: 320x260x120mm
> - Weight 2.5kg (box)
> - Apply suction cup to dry, clean surface
> - Requires small air compressor (not sold by GGR Group)
> - Hand cup requires 2 SCFM [57 litres/minute] @ 75 psi [517 kPa]

Comment: If it requires a small air compressor how did Steve do it?

Comment: @William Looks like it's in the backpack.

Comment: If you watch the video he is obviously hand pupping which means these can't be it.

Comment: @William "Vacuum is applied and released with quick action pump handle. Red line indicator warns of any vacuum loss." He's not pumping. Do you really believe that you can suck-on a human with three easy pumps? You have to activate the vacuum with the pump-handle by a pump movement. Also what do you think are the black wires into his backpack for? More badass design? :)

Comment: @William Also think about the backpack itself. Why would he even wear a backpack if there weren't any significant reason to do so?

Comment: Did you watch the video he doesn't go into his backpack to get anything.  We have found the real ones we believe https://www.zoro.com/powr-grip-suction-cup-lifter-8-in-horiz-hndl-metal-n4950/i/G0369205/?gclid=CKvZ7uH9t84CFc5bfgodU6sEGA&gclsrc=aw.ds the backpack had identification and a laptop in it.

Comment: @William Yep, sounds valid.

Answer (score 3):

The climber was using a [Powr-Grip Suction Cup Lifters](https://www.zoro.com/powr-grip-suction-cup-lifter-8-in-horiz-hndl-metal-n4950/i/G0369205/?gclid=CKvZ7uH9t84CFc5bfgodU6sEGA&gclsrc=aw.ds).

[image: Powr-Grip Suction Cup Lifters]

The full list of equipment can be found [here](http://www.outsideonline.com/2105706/what-gear-did-trump-tower-climber-use).

Comment: Out of curiosity if it is only for 125 lb. how does the physics or math work such that four can carry him.  I me you would guess four would be enough but I wouldn't feel particular safe about it.

Comment: These make more sense to me https://www.zoro.com/powr-grip-suction-cup-lifter-10-in-horiz-handle-n6450/i/G2473432/ because they are weighted for 175 a piece

Comment: Well. 4 of them don't compound in a full 500lb load but instead distribute (if proper used) his weight by 4. let's say he's 150lb heavy, each suction cup would only hold (again if proper used) around 37.5lb. He's a climber and I believe he understands or had people that understand that kind of physics to help him plan.

Comment: It would be better to say how much of the 3 suction cups each one holds considering one is off when he moves.

Comment: may as well. You can note he takes quite a long time to move from one to another. I believe it's because he must be sure the other three cups are secure. I opened a lot of climbing routes back home and we had to use [fifi hooks] (http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/big-wall-climbing/fifi-hook-BD6200650000ALL1.html). I always had a dozen hooked on various places and in many occasions, I only had enough time to drill the hole and secure the bolt by the time 8 or 9 of them had popped off.